# Google Service No Key could be detected

Tags: google-developers-console

I have created a **google** **service account**.

My application was working fine before, I just had to change the service account from my **personal** to **company wide**.

I can see that my application does create credential file, means I'm getting all these values

```
("auth_provider_x509_cert_url",
    "auth_uri",
    "client_email",
    "client_id",
    "client_x509_cert_url",
    "private_key",
    "private_key_id",
    "project_id",
    "token_uri",
    "type",)
```

I'm getting all values but the error message says

```
site-packages/google/auth/crypt/_python_rsa.py", line 171, in from_string
    raise ValueError("No key could be detected.")
ValueError: No key could be detected.
```

I have also given the role as **admin** to this **service account**

Any idea where should I look at? because I have checked everywhere. It seems that that key is not valid but when I check my key, it is listed in **service account** in **google console**

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me when the `private_key` was invalid.

It needs to be the following format:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

Comment: Exactly the issue. Thanks for pointing!