AWS Lambda unable to work with \n as string
I have a private key from GCP Pub Sub.
It is stored like this
secret_manager_data = {'google_pubsub_private_key':'-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nYourPrivateKeyHere\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'}

I'm now parsing the private key in the below code
signer = crypt.Signer.from_string(secret_manager_data['google_pubsub_private_key'])

Now I am getting an error like "No key could be detected"
But when I give string directly, then it is working. Example:
signer = crypt.Signer.from_string('-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nYourPrivateKeyHere\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n')

Means no issue in input but don't know how to handle \n in Lambda Function. Lambda is taking \n as next line instead of string.
Can you please help me?

How does the value of secret_manager_data['google_pubsub_private_key'] differ from the hard-coded string that you've presented in the 2nd test (the one that works)?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67600978/google-service-no-key-could-be-detected

When I append a string with '\n' to other variable, Lambda is automatically converts it to '\n'

I think you're saying the original data contains \n but when presented to your Lambda function that has been escaped to \\n. Not sure how to unescape it automatically but you could do it manually e.g. mystr.replace("\\n", "\n").

Thanks, This is the solution. Now it is working.

It looks like the \n newlines in the source event are being escaped to \\n before presentation to your Lambda function.
One way to deal with this is to unescape them, as follows:
mystr.replace("\\n", "\n"))

Example:
>>> print("fake\\nnews\\nhere".replace("\\n", "\n"))
fake
news
here

